# How can i store a formatted string in json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am trying to use a doc store which requires me to store my data in a valid json format. In my case one of the fields is the text of mail merge text which has single as well as double quotes and curly braces like the below example.

```
Hi {{ first_name | fallback: "there" }},

I gave you a call for our scheduled appointment today but wasn't able to reach you. I'm still 
happy to chat, so let's get a new time on the calendar. Send a few new times that work for you and I’ll give you a ring.

Thanks,

{{ my_first_name | fallback: "" }}
```

wondering if there is a function which can be used to escape the doc to make it valid json so it can be saved as well as turn it back into a plain string without escape char when i read it for processing.

Comment: base64 encode it perhaps? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: you can stringify this message and store. When retrieved you can parse it.  `var data = JSON.stringify(`message`); `  `JSON.parse(data);` Use backquote for the message.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure if I'm reading it correctly but worth a shot

[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

and then this to parse it out

[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Yes, stringify and parse does what i need. Only issue is that i have to stringify the string before i send it to my rest api as a json doc as otherwise express will throw still an error. But the doc server has no problem anymore saving the doc and i can convert it back with parse as well

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify can handle any string.

```
const weirdChars = `Hi {{ first_name | fallback: "there" }}`;
const doc = { text: weirdChars };
const docStr = JSON.stringify(doc);
```